# How to make the I-cursor smaller in a text field

Tags: 14.04, mouse, cursor

How do I make the i-cursor thinner when you want to type something? Any help would be great. Make the I-cursor that looks thick look like this:

[image]

Comment: Depends on the font you are using. Try changing the font and see.

Comment: I dont know how to though?